# Shortcut for reference searching in Scala IDE (cmd+shift+G)

Tags: eclipse, scala, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like to find all references to certain methods within my workspace. I used to do this using Eclipse's <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> / <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> hotkeys for all my Java classes, but now nothing shows up when searching in Scala classes using the Eclipse Scala IDE.

I'm currently using Scala IDE for Eclipse v3.0.3.

Is this reference searching functionality already supported in the Scala IDE, and if so, what is the shortcut for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too and I ended up installing the Eclipse [Quick Search plugin](http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/11/eclipse-quick-search/) from the Spring team that normally ships as part of STS.  It has no Spring dependencies and is easy to install separately from the Eclipse Marketplace.  Use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and start typing and you get incremental search results.

Answer (score 0):

Find references is implemented as feature but it is far away from being as powerful as the Java implementation.

You can find the actual key combination if you do a right click in the editor area and navigate to the "References" entry.

However, if the find references feature doesn't find anything, then it is clearly a bug and it would be nice if you could report your use case in the [ticket tracker](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/support/tickets).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [Scala-Search](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-search)? It's available from the same update site as the Scala IDE itself, and it should find Scala references. See [Features](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-search/wiki/Features) docs.